# How to achieve a three-step requiring process in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm struggling with "modularizing" my code into smaller pieces. I get it that if I have different routing files, I can use it like:

```
var apiUserRoutes = require('./app/routes/api/user')(app, express);
app.use('/api/user', apiUserRoutes);

var apiPostRoutes = require('./app/routes/api/post')(app, express);
app.use('/api/post', apiPostRoutes);
```

And in each of these files:

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.route('...')
    ...

    return router;
};
```

If we call it a two-step requiring process, then what I'm trying to achieve is a three-step requiring process. Say, we have a following project structure:

```
-server.js
-app
---routes
-----api.js
-----someOtherRoutes.js
-----api
-------user.js
-------post.js
-------blog.js
-----someOtherRoutes
-------thing.js
-------item.js
```

I want to require `user.js`, `post.js`, `blog.js` into `api.js` and `thing.js`, `item.js` into `someOtherRoutes.js`, and then require `api.js` and `someOtherRoutes.js` into main file `server.js`.

Comment: @Plato, I tried a two-step approach, and I get how it works, but I don't want to keep all the api routes in one place, since it gets messy.. If I export the router in `app/routes/api/user.js` and want to use `app/routes/api.js` for all the routes in my app with `/api`, e.g. `GET app.dev/api/users`, then I don't get what should happen in the `app/routes/api.js` file. Obviously, I need to export a router object from it in modules.export, but it will have different routers imported from `user.js`, `blog.js`, etc., so I need a bit of advice or a direction of thought how `api.js` should look like

Comment: This looks like it could get really messy, especially if user, post, blog etc also need access to `app`. I would move to a more flat require system, such as the one i posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477523/nodejs-my-node-files-have-dependencies-on-variables-in-an-other-file/31479004#31479004 With that setup, you would just `require('../app')` wherever it's needed. Though, you'd have to also make sure your path to app.js is correct based on the location of the file that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you bind the routes directly within the requires.

```
// app.js
require('./app/routes/api.js')(app, express);

// api.js
module.exports = function(app, express){ ...
  // if user.js exports a function(req, res<, next>){} bind it:
  app.use('/api/user', require('./api/user.js'));

  // if post.js exports a function(app, express){} and binds by itself just run it:
  require('./api/post.js')(app, express);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for my case I found the following solution:

### app/routes/api/user.js

```
module.exports = function(app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/test', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Test!');
    });

    return router;
};
```

### app/routes/api/router.js

```
var userRoutes = require('./user');

module.exports = function(app, express){
    var router = express.Router();

    router.use('/users', userRoutes(app, express));

    return router
};
```

### app/routes/routes.js

```
var apiRoutes = require('./api/router');

module.exports = function(app, express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.use('/api', apiRoutes(app, express));

    return router;
};
```

And now hitting `GET http://app.dev/api/users/test` I get the desired result, so basically I include `user.js` and all other api-specific routes into main api-router file `router.js` via `router.use(...)`, in every other routes with certain prefix like `http://app.dev/someOtherRoute` I can do the same. Then I include all `router.js` files from every subfolder into main `routes.js`, and then I include only this file into my `server.js`. Seems clean to me.